# XML format for personal information?

Tags: xml, xsd, file-format

Is there an universally acknowledged format for exchange information about 'a person'? I mean stuff like first name, last name, address, contact_address + some custom additional information. Is it better to define an ad-hoc schema or to use some ready made namespace. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is the [hCard](http://microformats.org/wiki/hcard) micro-format that can be embedded in XML.

Answer (score 1):

This question is really old, but if anyone get's here via google, there is a vCard XML representation that has become a de facto standard: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6351. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VCard#xCard.